# Disable closeButton in 2nd ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3, viewcontroller

Im trying to disable the closeButton in my second ViewController "OptionsVC"

Here's what I tried:

```
self.view.window!.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.closeButton)!.isHidden = true
```

Did that, got this:
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0

Also tried

```
var button = view.window?.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.ZoomButton)
button?.isEnabled = false
```

No changes

Comment: I don't understand if you only have one window and you're trying to enable/disable the close button in two different situations or if you have two windows and want to have one with a close button and one without it. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
override func viewDidAppear(){
super.viewDidAppear()

if let window1 = self.view.window
  {
    window1.styleMask.remove( [.closable, .resizable] )
  }
}
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable a button, it should be initialized. Therefore, you will face problems disabling the button from another view controller. Try adding a boolean and on viewDidLoad() check the boolean and decide either to enable or disable the button.